# How to get videos from specific folder in ListView with thumbnail and text , like youtube

Tags: android, directory, mediastore

I'm trying to show video thumbnail and text in a Listview from specific folder.
I am getting the thumbnails,but when i add text to a video and update using ContentValues,
I get the text on all videos. I saved the videos in a custom folder "/sdcard/myfolder/".

this is how i save the video captured(custom camera recorder):

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
Uri base = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;// how to specify folder
Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);
```

I'm getting all videos from gallery, how to specify a folder.

This is how i try adding text to each video in Listview:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);     
values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DESCRIPTION, edtext.getText().toString());
//values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, videoFile.getAbsolutePath());
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
Uri base = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
contentResolver.update(base, values,null,null);
```

This adds same text to all videos....any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);     
values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DESCRIPTION, edtext.getText().toString());
//values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, videoFile.getAbsolutePath());
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
Uri base = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
contentResolver.update(base, values,null,null);
```

appears to be trying to insert and update values in a database... If you want to take values from a database and display them in a listView I would recommend looking at this [tutorial](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/)

If you are truly just wanting to pull items from a folder and display them in a list I would recommend using a Custom ListViewAdapter tutorial [here](http://united-coders.com/phillip-steffensen/android-dealing-with-listactivities-customized-listadapters-and-custom-designed-0). Where he is using Twitter Api you will be replacing that code with IO stuff for the directory mentioned...